# Trying to hide a field in a list form in SharePoint Record Center

Tags: sharepoint-online

Sorry in advance, I am not that well versed in any coding at all and yet is trying to troubleshoot the following code.

It is able to hide the field at the start but does not show the field when it meets the condition of selecting "Other" from the drop-down.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var selectFieldName="Project Type"; // dropdown field display name
    var otherFieldName="Project Name";// single line of text field display name
    $("input[title='"+otherFieldName+"']").closest("tr").hide();
    $("select[title='"+selectFieldName+"']").change(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Other"){
            $("input[title='"+otherFieldName+"']").closest("tr").show();
        }else{
            $("input[title='"+otherFieldName+"']").closest("tr").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you also paste html from view source, I suspect your dropdown on change method is not getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code in my online environment,it works fine, try to confirm the jQuery library loaded(chrome developer tool->F12).
[image]

[image]

Update:

[image]

Comment: Hi Lee_MSFT, I have my jquery library in my SiteAssets but can't seem to have it load in my Chrome Console. Do you have a guide for me to reference to?

Comment: Try to save the js file to SiteAssets library and reference it from SiteAssets library. <script src="/sites/lee/SiteAssets/jquery-3.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I have did that and only partial of the above code seems to be working. My "Project Name" is currently hidden but changing the "Project Type" does not unhide the field. This should means the js file has no problem loading correct?

Comment: Yea, Then, you need confirm the element/attribute matches. I upload a screenshot.

Comment: I feel like a dummy right now, I added a mandatory required field and did not realize it will change the title of the field. You have been of great help, @Lee_MSFT

Comment: You could accept it as answer so the troubleshooting steps may help others.